# Fixing "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." error in python for importing rasterio

Tags: python, import, pip, package, rasterio

I am trying to download the package `rasterio` for analyzing raster datasets in python within the geospatial analysis disciplines.

I have downloaded the package dependencies for rasterio, including `gdal`, `pyproj`, and `fiona` via the wheel files from this geospatial analysis binaries resource: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

I installed these packages through `pip`.

I then downloaded from this resource the wheel file `rasterio` through `pip`.

I received the following message from `Window Command Prompt` after installing `rasterio`: `Successfully installed affine-2.3.0 numpy-1.21.4 pyparsing-3.0.6 rasterio-1.2.10 snuggs-1.4.7`.

I want to use this package in `Jupyter Notebook`, and so I open a `Jupyter Notebook` file and run `import rasterio`, and receive this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-350e27267e59> in <module>
----> 1 import rasterio

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py in <module>
     15 from pathlib import Path
     16 
---> 17 from rasterio._base import gdal_version
     18 from rasterio.drivers import driver_from_extension, is_blacklisted
     19 from rasterio.dtypes import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I address this "DLL load failed" issue and address this error so that I can use `rasterio`? I was told this could be an issue of not having `Visual C++` installed on my computer, and so I installed `Visual Studio 2022` on my computer, but this did not help.

Comment: Make sure you have GDAL 3.3.3 from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs installed and no other conflicting GDAL or GEOS DLLs in the DLL search path. In general it's not good practice to mix conda and pip packages.

Comment: A slightly older version of rasterio seems to work fine, try to install rasterio 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following steps:

1. I created a fresh environment
2. I installed the gdal library (since rasterio is built on top of it), with the command:

   conda install -c conda-forge gdal
3. I installed rasterio with the command:

   conda install -c conda-forge rasterio

Answer (score 0):

Cause of failure based on my observations:
When I used Python 3.7, there was no such error. However, after I upgraded the Python Version to Python 3.8.13; the above-mentioned error occurred.

Proposed solution:
Create a new Conda Environment with a Specific Python Version (I used Python=3.7) and use conda-forge to install all the necessary packages (rasterio=1.2.4, rioxarray=0.9.1, xarray=0.19.0, and earthpy=0.9.4) with the specified version or based on the conda list that successfully ran your project when you ran your project with Python 3.7. More details about the packages can be found at https://anaconda.org/

Answer (score 0):

try to use
pipwin install gdal

and then rasterio, etc. This worked for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).